# get number from string.format c#

Tags: string, c#-4.0

I have use string.format:
 string strfm = "PC{0:ddMMyy}.{1:d3}/{2:MM}H" and  number : 1
=>string str = string.format("PC{0:ddMMyy}.{1:d3}/{2:MM}H",DateTime.Now,1,DateTime.Now)
result str = PC070518.001/05H

=> str = strfm + number,
how to result number{1:d3} from str and strfm,
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use RegEx to get that number, something like this may help you:

`\.(\d{3})`

The number (`001`) will be in the first group. The full match will be `.001`.